# How to make image with different height appear in same height while staying responsive,

Tags: css, responsive-design

H everyone. Please help me out. I am using this grid based framework. in the middle I have 3 images like this

```
<section class="row">   
  <div class="col-4">
  <img src="img/seo.jpg" alt="seo work" class="work-type">
  <h3 class="work-title">seo specialist</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  <img src="img/webdesign.jpg" alt="web design work" class="work-type">
  <h3 class="work-title">web designer</h3>
```

And for the specific img class I am having this CSS for making it responsive

```
.work-type{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now. three images have different height and they are taking different space height wise inside the grid box. what CSS do I use to have them all appear with the same height?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with CSS and background images.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyZxoP

In this codepen, I display your current issue with the proposed solution.

If you want the images to be a part of the markup, then you'll need to provide more information about the solution you're looking for. (What should happen with the images that are being forced to become the same dimensions? Are we stretching them? Cropping? Are these images dynamically loaded? Hardcoded in the source? Are they featured images for a custom post type, like a staff post-type? Is this wordpress? Contextual layout details would be good, too.)

I've given divs the background-image properties to quickly/easily avoid skewing and stretching, as well as any other form of distortion because of layout stuff. This method can be used for responsive layouts as well.

```
.img-cont{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I was just making a responsive page as part of my project. For now I solved the problem by using 3 image of same original height and width. But I believe there should be other ways of doing it. It was a grid design framework so maybe there is a way to make the images take as much height as the box allows. So the larger image will have to adjust to that size.